# I have regex but its not catch angle bracket

Tags: regex, regex-negation

I have regex :

```
[RegularExpression(@"^(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=(.*[a-z]){1,})(?=(.*[\d]){1,})(?=(.*[\W]){1,})(?!.*\s).{8,40}$", 
                   ErrorMessage = "Minimum 8, max 40 characters atleast 1 Uppercase, 1 Lowercase, 1 Number and 1 Special Character")]
```

I want no special characters like *<, >(angle brackets)*. So can anyone help me?

Comment: Note that the capturing groups and the `{1,}` quantifiers aren't required here. Also, you can safely get rid of the `[` and `]` surrounding both `\d` and `\W` (you only need a character class if you're matching multiple characters and/or a range of characters). See my answer below for the improved pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the following pattern:

```
^(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*\W)[^\s<>]{8,40}$
```

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/QPR8bn/1)**.

Note that your original pattern had some redundant parts. For example, the capturing groups, some of the character classes, and the `{1,}` quantifiers; so, they were removed.

**Breakdown of the pattern:**

- `^` - Beginning of the string.
- `(?=.*[A-Z])` - Must contain at least one uppercase letter.
- `(?=.*[a-z])` - Must contain at least one lowercase letter.
- `(?=.*\d)` - Must contain at least one digit.
- `(?=.*\W)` - Must contain at least one non-word character.
- `[^\s<>]{8,40}` Match between 8 and 40 characters excluding whitespace characters and angle brackets.
- `$` - End of the string.